# VBA Macro to Paste Chart from Excel, into Word, and Format with Text Wrapping

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In my excel document I have a chart that I want to copy and paste into a MS-Word document. I want to avoid linking data, embedding workbooks and resizing (Excel has the chart formatted to my desired size). So I came up with/found the following code that almost works:

```
Sub PasteChart()

Dim wd As Object
Dim ObjDoc As Object
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\name\Desktop"
FileName = "Template.docx"


'check if template document is open in Word, otherwise open it
On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
Else
    On Error GoTo notOpen
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents(FileName)
    GoTo OpenAlready
notOpen:
    Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
End If
OpenAlready:
On Error GoTo 0

'find Bookmark in template doc
wd.Visible = True
ObjDoc.Bookmarks("LPPU").Select

 'copy chart from Excel
 Sheets("Group Level Graphs").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

 'insert chart to Bookmark in template doc
 wd.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=14, Placement:=0, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False

 End Sub
```

The only issue is that the image is pasted as "In Line with Text" but I need it to be "Square with text wrapping". I can't get Word or Excel to record changing the image to "Square with text wrapping".

The `PasteSpecial` part only does `wdFloatOverText` or `wdInLine` for placement and neither of them solve this issue.

I am very new to VBA and have run out of ideas. I am still trying to find a way to format it, maybe using some kind of `WITH` statement. However I thought I would attempt to reach out for help while I continue google-foo and learning VBA from Youtube.

Using `PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture` links the chart to excel. So that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to the Word application in your VBE then immediately following a regular paste (wd.Selection.Paste), add these two lines of code:

```
wd.Selection.MoveStart word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
wd.Selection.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
```

If you want to continue to use the PasteSpecial method you have in your code then replace the code line above "wd.Selection.MoveStart..." to this:

```
wd.Selection.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

The reason is a regular paste leaves the active insertion point at the end of the inserted object. But if a PasteSpecial method is used the active insertion point is at the beginning of the object that was pasted. Why? I have no idea! Word VBA never ceases to amaze me. :-)

Comment: @Thomas, I have adjusted the Answer above based on the comments you and I have shared. Stack Overflow likes to keep the comment strings short and the final correct answer to reflect any changes made based on temporary comments. I am cleaning up my comments as we've gone along. I recommend you do the same. Also if this final answer does the job for you, I hope you will mark it as answering your question.